# How do I configure JAIN-SIP client to send traffic to a non-standard port?

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I've checked other questions here are on Stack Overflow and googled, yet I can't seem to find an answer to my question: When using JAIN-SIP in a client implementation, how do I configure it to send SIP Requests to a server configured to use a non-standard port?

Here's the message I see in the log file:

```
<message
from="10.145.120.15:32095" 
to="54.241.2.206:5060" 
time="1424580783467"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="asdfgh3-6fc92a570580c48612146bb551a8b023-10.145.120.15-1-register-10.10.10.155-32095323632" 
callId="6fc92a570580c48612146bb551a8b023@10.145.120.15" 
firstLine="REGISTER sip:phone.plivo.com SIP/2.0" 
>
```

The 'To' line indicates that it is sending to port 5060. I need it to send sip traffic to a sip server configured to use port **5063**. Is there a way to do this?

If it helps, here is the code I'm using to send the sip register request:

```
    // Create the "Request"
    Request request = this.messageFactory.createRequest("REGISTER sip:" + remoteServer + " SIP/2.0\r\n\r\n");
    request.addHeader(callIdHeader);
    request.addHeader(cSeqHeader);
    request.addHeader(fromHeader);
    request.addHeader(toHeader);
    request.addHeader(maxForwardsHeader);
    request.addHeader(viaHeader);
    request.addHeader(contactHeader);


    // Send the request
    this.sipProvider.sendRequest(request);  // Response received through SipListener method implementation on this class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the port in the request URI or Route header. For example

```
REGISTER sip:phone.plivo.com:5063 SIP/2.0
```